# Joining multiple counts on the same table, from different columns?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, aggregation, unpivot

I feel like this should be easy but it's late and I'm struggling.

Say (in an oracle 12 db) I have a table which represents which staff filled what roles in a bar, during different events, like this:

```
+----------+----------+-------+------------+----------+
| event_id | bar      | doors | cloak_room | keg_room |
+----------+----------+-------+------------+----------+
| 2        | bob      | bill  | john       | mary     |
+----------+----------+-------+------------+----------+
| 3        | bob      | bill  | mary       | kev      |
+----------+----------+-------+------------+----------+
| 4        | bob      | john  | louise     | mary     |
+----------+----------+-------+------------+----------+
| 5        | kyle     | kev   | sarah      | louise   |
+----------+----------+-------+------------+----------+
| 6        | jennifer | bob   | jay        | john     |
+----------+----------+-------+------------+----------+
| 7        | john     | bill  | mary       | steve    |
+----------+----------+-------+------------+----------+
```

and I want to get a count of, overall, how many events each staff member worked, like this:

```
+-------+--------+
| count | person |
+-------+--------+
| 4     | bob    |
+-------+--------+
| 4     | john   |
+-------+--------+
| 3     | bill   |
+-------+--------+
| 3     | mary   |
+-------+--------+
| 2     | kev    |
+-------+--------+
| 2     | louise |
+-------+--------+
| 1     | jay    |
+-------+--------+
| 1     | steve  |
+-------+--------+
```

We see here that bob has a count of 4 - because he is associated with 4 distinct event_id: 3 as a barman, and 1 as a doorman.

(assuming no two staff members have the same name, and no one can work two jobs at once)

How do I do this?

for one 'role' it's clear:

```
select count(event_id), bar group by bar
```

but is there an elegant way to do this for all columns - without full joins and string concat?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may *count* by string columns in the nested inner query and then *sum* them *up* outside with your desired *order* :

```
SELECT sum(count) count, person
  FROM
(
 SELECT count(event_id) count, bar person FROM mytable GROUP BY bar UNION ALL
 --> P.S. Only aliasing as "person" is enough in this upper "select" for all 
 --> four "select" statements inside the parentheses.
 SELECT count(event_id)      , doors      FROM mytable GROUP BY doors UNION ALL
 SELECT count(event_id)      , cloak_room FROM mytable GROUP BY cloak_room UNION ALL
 SELECT count(event_id)      , keg_room   FROM mytable GROUP BY keg_room
)
GROUP BY person
ORDER BY 1 desc, 2;

COUNT   PERSON
   4    bob
   4    john
   3    bill
   3    mary
   2    kev
   2    louise
   1    jay
   1    jennifer
   1    kyle
   1    mary2
   1    sarah
   1    steve
```

[***SQL Fiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/aafd49/9)

Comment: Hi @barbaros - thanks a bunch, that worked! 
If it were possible for a person to work multiple jobs in one event, (like this example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8d279/2 ) but we only wanted to count events associated with (not jobs worked) - is there an easy way to change the query to do that?

Comment: @Paul thank you too friend. As much as I understood you mean this : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8d279/26

Comment: works perfectly! I don't know why the unions are confusing me so much. Very much appreciate your help

Answer (score 2):

You should change the structure of your data, so you have one row per event/person/role.  Then you could just use aggregation.

You can do that in a query as well:

```
select who, count(*)
from (select event_id, 'bar' as job, bar as who from t union all
      select event_id, 'doors' as job, doors as who from t union all
      select event_id, 'cloak_room' as job, cloak_room as who from t union all
      select event_id, 'keg_room' as job, keg_room as who from t
     ) jw
group by who;
```

If someone could have multiple jobs in one event, then use `count(distinct event_id)`.

EDIT:

I see you are using Oracle 12c.  Then use a lateral join/cross apply:

```
select who, count(*)
from t cross apply
     (select t.event_id, 'bar' as job, t.bar as who from dual union all
      select t.event_id, 'doors' as job, t.doors as who from dual from dual union all
      select event_id, 'cloak_room' as job, cloak_room as who from dual union all
      select t.event_id, 'keg_room' as job, t.keg_room as who from dual
     ) jw
group by who;
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! the part where you say "if someone could have multiple jobs in one event, then use count(distinct event_id)". If it were possible to work two jobs at once, and I wanted to count someone working two jobs in the same event only once in the overall count - how would I do that? If I add 'distinct event_id' I still get the same results either way?